# SSH Outbound. Tracking down the process

Tags: linux, ssh, system-compromise

I was pulled up by my ISP in work for having a machine making dozens of outbound SSH connections. I tracked down the machine and took it off the network. Problem is there are several other machines with identical configs that potentially could suffer a similar fate.

I can see outbound connection attempts using tcpdump but im having trouble trying to track down the script or process making these connection attempts. I've been trying to use `netstat -plunt`, `ss -tp`, `lsof` and various commandline utils but haven't been able to source the offending process. Has anyone any advice on tracking down processes and applications on compromised boxes like this?

```
sudo netstat -plunt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1339/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1008/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1024/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1413/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1008/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      1022/perl           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1024/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1413/cupsd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37790           0.0.0.0:*                           938/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54446           0.0.0.0:*                           1364/openvpn        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           938/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           1008/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1008/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           1414/cups-browsed   
udp6       0      0 :::53487                :::*                                938/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                938/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                1008/systemd-resolv
```

Comment: "but haven't been able to source the offending process" - do you see the connections, but not the process, or can you not see the connections at all?

Comment: What do you see from netstat? One hacky alternative may be to replace the ssh client on the machine with a script that logs the parent PID / name.

Comment: @schroeder I don't see the connections. tcpdump shows the traffic. netstat doesn't show these client connections outbound. 
@Hector I could `ln -s` to a logging process I suppose. I thought there might be something really basic I'm missing. Some terminal command that I'm not aware of
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1024/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1413/cupsd
...
Sample output. I don't see any of the foreign addresses from tcpdump listed on netstat.

Comment: What may be happening is that the connections are sporadic. You would need to log the changes over time to see the connections.

Comment: netstat -plunt includes the -l flag so it only shows listening connections.  Outbound connections won't be shown by it.  ssh is tcp so netstat -pnt would probably work or the ss -pt you tried but haven't provided the output for.

Answer (score 2):

Do you think that you can have a rootkit installed that does not allow you to see the offending process?

Another idea is to use the command `watch`, to try to spot the offending process.

`watch -d 'lsof -i tcp:22'`

`watch -d` highlights the differences. It runs the command every 2 secs.

`lsof -i tcp:22` gives you a list of processes that use TCP connections on port 22.

In case you suspect of a rootkit, you can compile busybox and use it to check your processes and open files.